# Run block of code only if object found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a cleaner way to only run a block of code if an object is found? I'm currently testing to see if the param even exists. This would error out I'm sure if there was no object. Please excuse the ugly code:

```
def show
  if params[:event_entry].to_i>1
    event_entry = EventEntry.find(params[:event_entry])
    #### Do something with event_entry here
  end
end
```

There has to be a much better way to go about this then I am...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An even cleaner way to do this (in Rails 4) is:

```
def show
  if event_entry = EventEntry.find_by(id: params[:event_entry])
    # Do something with `event_entry` here
  end
end
```

`find_by` will return `nil` if a record doesn't exist, see: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by

EDIT:

As mentioned by @apneadiving in the comment below, it would also be nice if this was done using an abstract method so you could call `before_filter` and the start of your controller for applicable methods (such as `show`, `edit`, `update` and `delete`). I've included an example of this below.

```
class EventEntriesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_event_entry, only: :show

  def show
    # You have access to @event_entry because it was set before this method was called
  end

  private

  def set_event_entry
    @event_entry = EventEntry.find_by(id: params[:event_entry])
  end
end
```

Now you can add other methods to the `before_filter` line at the start of your controller to gain access to `@event_entry` in those methods. Something like

```
before_filter :set_event_entry, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

should do the trick.

Note: You may also see `before_action` used in some places instead of `before_filter`. Either of these will work.

Comment: ok but its better to abstract it in a method to reuse in other actions

Comment: @apneadiving I agree completely... if this was going to be something used in every method you should use `before_filter` and set `@event_entry` before applicable methods, ie. `show`, `edit`, `delete` and `update`. However your answer didn't quite show how to do that all the way (you're missing `before_filter`). Although your method would work, it's not very Rails-4-ish. I've updated my answer to show how this should be done.

Comment: The before is not required for update and delete since you'll call the method to work on the object

Comment: Be aware its a design pattern, thus a good practice, to abstract local variables to methods. It should be advised.

Comment: You would still use the `before_filter` for `update` and `destroy` (sorry, meant `destroy` not `delete`, guessing that's what you are referring to). eg. you would have access to `@event_entry` in your `destroy` method and then simply do `@event_entry.destroy` and possibly a `respond_to` block.

Every Rails project I have worked on recently uses `before_filter` and a `set_model_name` method to provide access to a class instance in the controller methods, and considering it is the default Rails 4 approach I think it's safe to say the example I provided in my answer is good practice to follow.

Comment: You can, its just not necessary. I'm not sayung you're wrong. First things first: abstract, then if necessary use a callback (but beware of callbacks)

Comment: I wasn't clear in my write up for sure. It happens that in this case I only wanted to run it in the show action and no other action. Good chance I'm doing something the wrong way for sure;-) Still learning the rails way to do a lot of things. Don't get me wrong, the Rails way always seems better then my way... Thanks for everyones help!!!

Comment: Glad you learned something new today! Enjoy your Rails learning experience.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do:

```
def show
  if event_entry
    #### Do something with event_entry here
  end
end

private

def event_entry
  @event_entry ||= EventEntry.find_by(id: params[:event_entry]) # which returns nil if params[:event_entry] is nil
end
```

If you really want to check `params[:event_entry]` is present, do:

```
def event_entry
  return nil unless params[:event_entry]
  @event_entry ||= EventEntry.find_by(id: params[:event_entry])
end
```

I dont feel like checking its an integer really worth it

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
def show
  if event_entry = EventEntry.where(id: params[:event_entry]).first
    # Do something with `event_entry` here
  end
end
```